# Expanding the scope of "money" to economics, etc

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm posting to get opinions on whether or not the scope of this exchange should be expanded. Many people ask questions regarding relationships between the Fed and banks or other broader questions that aren't specifically "personal" finance. Now, first of all, economics can be a bit subjective, but certain things like, "How do changes in the Fed Funds Target Rate affect markets?" are plenty objective enough. Is this the main concern? I'm not sure if we could trust the community to vote responsibly (I've seen Reddit's PF and investing subs, pretty bad and not to be emulated).

Could we allow any finance or economics related questions, on the condition that they can get a very objective answer?

Comment: Related discussion in past http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/148/clarifying-the-area-51-proposal-can-some-basic-economics-and-policy-questions-b and http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/392/why-cant-we-ask-questions-about-economics-here-is-there-a-place-to-ask-questi

Answer (score 8):

I feel that economics questions are already well-served by the [economics stack exchange site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

While some questions on economics can make sense here, most don't. The community does not have expertise in answering quite a few economic concepts.

The difficulty this community is facing is can we create a clear Q & A that gives out the scope as to what sub-set of economic questions can be on-topic. In absence of such definition, it becomes subjective; i.e. you answer some your close some and does not give a good user experience and can create friction.

Given that we now have a new economics site; it does not make sense to expand the scope here.